# spatie/image-optimizer keep certain metadata

Tags: php, laravel, image, image-optimization

I am trying to keep certain metadata with spatie/image-optimizer image optimization library, but am not successful.

Is It even possible ?

I see no variables for metadata. Just strip all. Any help is appreciated.

```
(new OptimizerChain())
        ->addOptimizer(new Jpegoptim([
            $jpegQuality,
            '--strip-all',
            '--all-progressive',
        ]))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keep certain metadata"? Do you only want to keep some metadata and strip some other metadata? As you see, there is only the option to strip all, or keep all. Is that the problem you are facing? You probably need some other tool to selectively copy only some of the metadata to the output. Have you tried any? For example http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/

Comment: @Palo I am trying to keep certain metadata. Like Coordinates or Device. I did not found any information for spatie and searching for other tools.